# Disable many fields by name javascript

Tags: javascript, function, jsp, disabled-input

This is my question:

I got an jsp page, this jsp has many text fields like this:

```
<html:text property="cicPF" maxlength="9" style="text-transform: uppercase;" onfocus="disableIfeFields()"/>
```

So I want to disable some of this text fields when the focus it's in a specific field

But no one of this fields has "id" label, and I can't modify it to include it.

May I disable the fields usig their given names, no one of this repeats the same name.

for example with a function like this:

```
function disableIfeFields(){
    document.getElementsByName("numIdentificacionPF").disabled = true;

}
```

thanks

Comment: [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Use [`item()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/item)  method to retrieve a node (element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the list and disable all the fields you want that way, used input to show example:

```js
function disableIfeFields() {
  document.getElementsByName("numIdentificacionPF").forEach((e) => {
    e.disabled = true;
  });
}
```

```html
<html:text property="cicPF" maxlength="9" style="text-transform: uppercase;" />
<input onfocus="disableIfeFields()" type="text" name="fname">
<input type="text" name="numIdentificacionPF">
<input type="text" name="numIdentificacionPF">
<input type="text" name="numIdentificacionPF">
<input type="text" name="numIdentificacionPF">
<input type="text" name="numIdentificacionPF">
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully the following should help. Because the selection result is a list of elements you will have to loop through the results.
Please note that since you said no input repeats the same name, I'm using `querySelectorAll`, which might be a more suitable method after all…

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].id === 'label') {
        continue;
    }
    inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```js
function disableIfeFields(){
    document.querySelectorAll('[property="cicPF"]')[0].disabled = true;
}

disableIfeFields();
```

```html
<input type="text" property="cicPF" maxlength="9" style="text-transform: uppercase;" onfocus="disableIfeFields()"/>
```